# How to change svg color on Canvas - Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I'm creating an app with [Fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/). 
I have to add an SVG file to the canvas and change the color every time a [Minicolors](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/) input changes. 
I first made the browser display the SVG images as SVG codes like so:

```
$('img[src$=".svg"]').each(function(){
var $img = $(this),
    imgURL = $img.attr('src'),
    attributes = $img.prop('attributes');

$.get(imgURL, function(data) {
  // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
  var $svg = $(data).find('svg');
  // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
  $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
  // Make sure that every attribute was copied
  $.each(attributes, function() {
    $svg.attr(this.name, this.value);
  });
  // Replace image with new SVG
  $img.replaceWith($svg);
}, 'xml');
});
```

Then I loaded the SVG images from the DOM to the canvas when they get clicked on, like so:

```
$('#images').on('click', 'svg', function() {
  var serializer = new XMLSerializer(),
  svgStr = serializer.serializeToString(this);

  fabric.loadSVGFromString(svgStr,function(objects, options) {
    options.id = this.id;
    var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

    canvas.add(obj);

    obj.scaleToHeight(127) // Scales it down to some small size
       .scaleToWidth(90)
       .center() // Centers it (no s**t, Sherlock)
       .setCoords();

    canvas.setActiveObject(obj).renderAll();
  });
});
```

Now for my next goal, how do I change the path color of the selected svg file?
My main guess would be to follow these steps:

1. Save the left and top positions of the selected SVG
2. Change the color of the SVG image in the DOM
3. Remove the selected SVG object
4. Replace it with the new SVG using the new color at the saved left and top positions

But I thought: "So I have to do all this every time a Minicolors input changes? Won't that be a performance issue later?"

Is there a better approach than this? Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pp6233zc/) that will get you started. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When added to the canvas, the SVG object contains a property called "paths", which contains all the paths that build the image. So we do:

```
activeObject.paths.forEach(function(path) {path.fill = color});
```

But I wonder if it won't be a performance issue for huge SVG files (I won't get to that point, hopefully). Here's a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aLkkxghz/).

Comment: Performance will be better if you change the fill color in the object that represent the svg instead of changing the dom directly, without counting the extra work needed to serialize and reload.

Comment: Well, if you read the code carefully, you will notice that *selectedObject* is not a DOM element, it's the object that represents the SVG on the canvas. @AndreaBogazzi

Comment: I read it, and i was saying, better what you proposed in the answer than what you were guessing in the question. You solution is correct in the answer and it is what you should do. There is no better way once the SVG is loaded, and loading it again is slower. I would suggest adding a check to see if the fill is already there, otherwise you would fill also empty shapes.

Comment: Aah, thanks. What do you mean by empty shapes? The paths are what represent the drawing, so I don't think there will be transparent paths. @AndreaBogazzi

Comment: Sorry i mean shapes with empty fill, transparent.

Comment: Aah, I see what you mean. But when an SVG is added to the canvas, the transparent parts are not taken into account, what matter really are the paths, which will always have a fill color. At least, that's what I understand from my experience with canvas and SVG. @AndreaBogazzi

Comment: add a transparent path to your svg, and you will see it will get colored with forEach iteration.

Comment: Aah, makes sense. Thanks for the heads up. @AndreaBogazzi

Comment: Downvoted cuz doesn't work anymore with the current version of FabricJS. So sad!

Comment: Not work with fabricjs version 3.5. There is no `paths` attribute in the object.

Answer (score 6):

Answer by [Nick Rameau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36380964/3719167) is not working with the latest version of the fabricjs.

In my case, I'm working with `fabricjs 3.5`.

In the latest version of the fabricjs, the `paths` attribute has been removed. The `paths` data has been added to the `_objects` property.

This is how, I got it working for me.

```
var obj = this.canvas.itemObj;
var color = '#ff00ff';

if (obj && obj._objects) {
  for (var i = 0; i < obj._objects.length; i++) {
    obj._objects[i].set({
      fill: color
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What is itemObj here?

Comment: this.canvas.itemObj is undefined fabric v5.3.0